# Sencha Touch: filter dataview store with nested JSON data based on button click

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, sencha-touch

I have a dataview list that fetches data from the server, puts it in a store, and renders into a template. Standard stuff.

Above the dataview list in the UI is a button bar containing some Ext.Buttons. I want to be able tap a button and filter the list based on the name of the button.  For example: click on 'English 9A' button and show items in the list with the '**title**' of 'English 9A'.

As of now when I click the button, the list disappears and I get a console error of:  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'position' of undefined "  and a loading spinner where the list was.

I know there are similar questions out there but I've tried all the solutions but no luck at all.

Sample json data:

```
{
    "ftype":"Announcement",
    "value":{
        "created":"7/18/2013 05:40:06 PM",
        "content":"Hello class, it is July 29th. This is quiz",
        "announcementtypename":"HW",
        "announcementtypeid":2,
        "expiresdate":"2013-07-19",
        "isowner":false,
        "gradable":false,
        "starred":false,
        "id":172459,
        "order":1,
        "state":1,
        "statetyped":1,
        "qnacount":0,
        "attachmentscount":0,
        "ownerattachmentscount":0,
        "title":"Spanish 9A",
     }
},
{
    "ftype":"Announcement",
    "value":{
        "created":"7/18/2013 12:04:45 PM",
        "content":"Hello class, it is July 18th. Here is an essay",
        "announcementtypename":"HW",
        "announcementtypeid":2,
        "expiresdate":"2013-07-19",
        "isowner":false,
        "gradable":false,
        "starred":false,
        "id":172009,
        "order":61,
        "state":1,
        "statetyped":1,
        "qnacount":0,
        "attachmentscount":0,
        "ownerattachmentscount":0,
        "title":"English 9A",
     }
}
```

Model:

```
Ext.define('app.model.FeedModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        sorters: 'title',
        fields: [
            {name: 'content',               type: "string"},
            {name: 'created',               type: "string"},
            {name: 'announcementtypename',  type: "string"},
            {name: 'announcementtypeid',    type: "integer"},
            {name: 'attachmentscount',      type: "integer"},
            {name: 'applicationscount',     type: "integer"},
            {name: 'ftype',                 type: "string"},
            {name: 'title',                 type: "string"},
            {name: 'expiresdate',           type: "string"},
            {name: 'starred',               type: "boolean"}
        ]
    }
});
```

Store:

```
Ext.define('app.store.FeedStore',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    config:{
        storeId:'FeedStore',
        model:'app.model.FeedModel',
        filterRoot: 'title',          // * --does nothing
        filters: [          
            {
                property: 'title'     // * --does nothing
            }
        ],
    }
});
```

Controller: (Needs the help)

```
//the button name matches the "title" node in the json

filterFeedFunc: function(button){
    var name = button.config.name;
    var sto = Ext.getStore('FeedStore');
    var all = "allname";
    if (name == all){
        sto.clearFilter();         // when they click "all" it should show all items - doesn't work
    }

    //sto.clearFilter();           // * --doesn't work
    //sto.filter('title', name);  // * --doesn't work
    sto.filter({
        property: 'title',        // * --doesn't work, need something new here
        value: name,
        exactMatch: true
    });
    sto.load();   // no
},
```

**UPDATE / EDIT**

the View:

```
Ext.define('app.view.feed.Feed', {
    extend: 'Ext.dataview.List',
    xtype: 'Feed',
    alias: 'widget.feedlist',
    config: {
        cls: 'feedlist',
        store : 'FeedStore',
        model: 'FeedModel',
        title:'',
        emptyText:'no items',
        style: 'background-color:#ffffff',
        itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
            '<tpl for=".">'+
                '<div class="feed-item-box">'+
                        '<tpl if="values.starred == true"> <img src="img/Important.png"> </tpl>'+
                        '<tpl if="!values.starred"> <img src="img/not-starred.png"> </tpl>'+
                        '<div class="anntype"><h1>{announcementtypename} </h1></div>' +
                        '<div class="classname"><h2>{title:ellipsis(30)} </h2></div>' +
                        '<div class="content"><h4>{content:ellipsis(50)} {summary}</h4></div>' +
                        '<tpl if="values.attachmentscount || values.applicationscount"><div class="attachment-clip"></div> </tpl>' +    
                        '<div class="due"> ' +
                            '<h4>{[this.dueInfo(values.expiresdate)]} </h4>' +
                        '</div>' +
                '</div>'+
            '</tpl>',{

                getUrl: function(){
                    var store = Ext.getStore('UrlStore');
                    var url = store.last();
                    return url.data.url;
                },

                dueInfo: function(date){
                    var origDate = moment(date).format("MMMM Do");
                    var today = moment().format("MMMM Do");
                    if (today.match(origDate)){
                        return "Today"
                    } else{
                        return origDate
                    }
                }
        }),

        listeners:{

            refresh: function(records) {

                var me = this;
                var classes = Ext.getStore('ClassListStore')._data.items;                                               
                   me.setItems([{
                        cls          :  'classbar',
                        docked      : 'top',
                        xtype       : 'dataview',
                        inline: {
                            wrap: false
                        },
                        scrollable: {
                            direction: 'horizontal',
                            directionLock: true
                        },
                        height      : 101, 
                        html        : '<div class="select-all" style= "float: left"></div>',
                        itemTpl: ''.concat (
                            '<tpl for=".">',
                                '<div class="select-{id}"></div>',  
                            '</tpl>'

                        ),
                        store       : Ext.getStore('ClassListStore'),
                        model       : 'app.model.ClassListModel',
                        listeners:{

                            refresh: function(){

                                var bar = jQuery('.classbar');
                                function getUserRole(){
                                    var store = Ext.getStore('UserStore');
                                    store.load();
                                    var userRole = store.last();
                                    return userRole.data.roledescription;
                                }

                                if (getUserRole() != app.UserRoles.ADMIN){

                                    for(var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++){
                                        var data = classes[i].data;
                                        var render = Ext.DomQuery.select('.classbar .select-' + data.id)[0];
                                        var allbutren = Ext.DomQuery.select('.classbar .select-all')[0];
                                        var button = new Ext.Button({
                                            ui:            'chalk-light',
                                            text:          data.name,
                                            renderTo:      render,
                                            name:           data.name,
                                            clazzId:        data.id,
                                            cls:            'class-button',
                                            action:         'filterFeed',
                                            html: '<img width="45" style="margin-top: -45px;" src="https://www.app.com/Course/GetIcon?courseInfoId=' + data.courseinfoid + '"/>' +
                                                '<div class="classnamer">' + data.name +  '</div>'
                                        });

                                        var allbutton = new Ext.Button({
                                            ui:             'chalk-light',
                                            text:           'All',
                                            renderTo:       allbutren,
                                            name:           'allname',
                                            clazzId:        'someId',
                                            cls:            'class-button x-button-pressing',
                                            action:         'filterFeed',
                                            html: '<img width="45" style="margin-top: -45px;" src="https://www.app.com/Content/images/common/course-icons/all.png"/>' +
                                                '<div class="classnamer">All</div>'
                                        });
                                    }

                                } else{
                                    bar.hide();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                        ,
                        {
                            cls          :  'feedbar',
                            itemId      :  'something',
                            docked      : 'top',
                            xtype       : 'panel',
                            items:[
                                {
                                    xtype: 'panel',
                                    html:'Feed',
                                    cls: 'feedTitle'
                                },
                                {
                                    xtype: 'button',
                                    action: 'feedAll',
                                    text: 'All',
                                    cls: 'allBtn',
                                    ui: 'chalk-light'
                                    //see feedController.all()
                                },
                                {
                                    xtype: 'button',
                                    action: 'starred',
                                    cls: 'impBtn',
                                    ui: 'chalk-light',
                                    html: '<img src="img/not-starred.png"> &nbsp; Important'
                                }
                            ]
                        }]
                    );
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Is that store loaded data ? did you got store data in dataview ?

Comment: dataview list displayed all the data from the store ?

Comment: Yes all data loads into the dataview nicely

Comment: did you tried below answer

Comment: you have list and some buttons in a view and you want to filter the list based on the button.. am i right ?

Comment: yes that is right.  the button config contains the name that corresponds with the "title" node from the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to set filterRoot and filters property in store, Try this and let me know what happened.

```
filterFeedFunc: function(button){
   var name = button.config.name;
   var sto = Ext.getStore('FeedStore');
   sto.load(function(records, operation, success) {
      if(sto.getCount()){   
        if (name == "allname")
        sto.clearFilter();         
        else
        sto.filter("title", name);
     }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I tried this and still get the same issue. When I put breakpoints on all of the lines from sto.load()... and down, none of them break and (records, operations, success) dont even register as scope variables. When I do pause execution after clicking "English 9A" button and call sto.getAllCount() directly in the console it still returns the original count of 40.

Comment: @jakeed1 in which line Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'position' of undefined error coming ?

Comment: @jakeed1  sto.getAllCount() Gets the number of all cached records including the ones currently filtered

Comment: Was just checking that - sencha-touch-all.js:3337 ..  the undefined var is "scroller"

Comment: Update - could the issue be with my view in the 'refresh' func? I added the view code in the description